How to disable functools @lru_cache when developing locally
How do you disable caching when working with pythons functools? We have a boolean setting where you can disable the cache. This is for working locally.
I thought something like this:
@lru_cache(disable=settings.development_mode)
But there is no setting like that. Am I missing something? How are people doing this?

Are people doing this? lru_cache is something that probably shouldn't be disabled, it should be part of your code unconditionally. You may have other kinds of caches, like HTTP headers etc, which have different settings in productions vs. development. But that's your own business logic code, not anything integrated into Python.

@deceze Ok I see. But how do you test changes during development in a function which has this decorator? After the first call the function will not be called anymore.

If you want to disable caching conditionally while using functools.lru_cache, you need to manage this manually, You need a decorator that can conditionally apply lru_cache based on your settings
I am using the docs as the guide docsOnFunctools
Quotes from docs:

If maxsize is set to None, the LRU feature is disabled and the cache
can grow without bound.If typed is set to true, function arguments of
different types will be cached separately. If typed is false, the
implementation will usually regard them as equivalent calls and only
cache a single result. (Some types such as str and int may be cached
separately even when typed is false.)

from functools import lru_cache, wraps

def remove_lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False, enable_cache=True):
    def decorator(func):
        if enable_cache:
            return lru_cache(maxsize=maxsize, typed=typed)(func)
        return func
    return decorator

Then you can apply it to your code
# settings
your_settings = {
    'dev_mode': True  #set False to enable caching
}
@remove_lru_cache(maxsize=None, typed=False, enable_cache=not settings['dev_mode'])
def add(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    return sum(nums)


You could give a maxsize of 0 (or negative for that matter), which will effectively turn off the cache since no values can enter the cache at all.
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=0)
def f(a):
    print("entered the function in f")

@functools.lru_cache
def g(a):
    print("entered the function in g")

f(1) 
f(1) # -> will also show "entered the function in f", thus not using the cache
g(1)
g(1) # -> does not show anything, thus using the cache

For your example this means that you could use a variable to set the size, and when you want to disable it set that variable to 0.

You can apply the decorator conditionally instead:
def f(x):
    return 2 * x

if not settings.development_mode:
    f = lru_cache(f)


lru_cache exposes a few functions on the cached function.
E.g. cache_info(), cache_clear(), and __wrapped__()
So here's two options:

Clear the cache after each execution or
Call the underlying function directly, bypassing the lru_cache


import random


@lru_cache
def foo():
    return random.random()


def test_foo():

    foo()

    # Clear cache
    foo.cache_clear()
    # Call again
    foo()

    # Call underlying function, uncached
    foo.__wrapped__()    

cache_info() might also be useful for introspection of the cache status. E.g.
> foo.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=128, currsize=1)

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache
